# Conditional search along the columns of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, filtering

I want to implement the following algorithm in *Mathematica*.

1. Get element along main diagonal of a matrix.
2. If the element along the main diagonal is positive, then return the positions of the elements in the corresponding column that are negative.

   If the element along the main diagonal is negative, then return the positions of the elements in the corresponding column that are positive. The positions returned are the positions in the table.

   If neither of the two conditions above are true, do nothing.

Here is example of what I want

Given the matrix

```
{{1, 1, 1}, {2, -2, 2}, {-3, 3, 3}}
```

the algorithm should produce

> ```
> {{3, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 2}}
> ```

In the above, the first element of each pair is the row of an off-diagonal element, the second element of the pair is its column)

I'm currently trying to do this with a For-loop, but I can't get it to work.  Besides, because *Mathematica* is so good with lists, I'm sure that a functional solution is possible.

Comment: It should be done column by column or non sorted answer is ok too? :) Anyway, you can `SortBy[.., #[[2]]&]` my result if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
m = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, -2, 2}, {-3, 3, 3}};
d = Sign@Diagonal@m
Position[(m\[Transpose] d)\[Transpose], _?Negative]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}
> ```

Which looks way better in MMA:

> [image]

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting the OP, "corresponding col" means the absolute value of the diagonal (matches OP example), where results w/b `{{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}`. Perhaps OP can clarify. If it's just the same col, this is so trivial s/b closed...

Comment: @Kuba I have tested and I agree.  What you wrote looks correct. Since -1 is in position (1,1), then the only positive value in the column is in position (2,1). So it makes sense.

Comment: @olliepower: voted to close. This is so trivial, suggest you *read* the documentation & tutorials.

Comment: @rasher by corresponding column I mean the column that contains the particular diagonal element.

Comment: @rasher I'm not sure why you find it basic. To be honest I consider my answer quite neat :p

Comment: @kuba: Nothing to do with your answer, which *is* a nice, clean way of doing this. More to do with the recent rash of "questions" that are more like using the site as a mechanical-turk to search the documentation. This problem involves nothing more than three *very* basic functionalities of MMA. Hence my vote for "easily found in documentation"

Comment: @rasher are you referring to my recent set of questions?  Or are you referring to questions on the site in general?

Comment: @olliepower: No, no, I'm most certainly *NOT* singling you out. That would be pretty uncool in general, and you've asked some quite interesting questions. I meant in general, over the past few months (probably Rasberry Pi related) there seems to be a influx of "hey, do my work/search the docs for me" questions. Sorry if you thought I was poking you, *not* intended.

Comment: @rasher but this is a good sign actually. The more questions asked, it means M (opps, I mean Wolfram) language is getting popular! Which is a good thing (tm). If you check that other language (starts with M and ends up with B), almost all the question are along the line: "do it for me". So, this is a good sign if this starts to happen here too. (ps. nothing to do with this question, this was a nice question actually)

Comment: Very slick solution. +1

Answer (score 5):

I can't beat the elegance of Kuba's clean method so I'll focus on performance.

- Although it has little effect on performance it is worth noting that `Sign` is extraneous.
- `Position` is a general function that is quite slow compared to purely numeric methods.

I use `SparseArray` Properties to quickly find all non-background elements in a numeric array:

```
fn = SparseArray[
       UnitStep[(#\[Transpose] Diagonal[#])\[Transpose]],
       Automatic, 1
     ]["NonzeroPositions"] &;
```

This is well over an order of magnitude faster than `Position` on packed data:

```
m = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {2000, 2000}];

First @ Timing[r1 = Position[(m\[Transpose] (Sign@Diagonal@m))\[Transpose], _?Negative]]

First @ Timing[r2 = fn[m]]

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> 1.591
>
> 0.063
>
> True
> ```

Comment: nice solution. May be one should use SparseArray for more things if they are faster for packed data.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing close as nice as Kuba solution.

```
Clear[x, n, p, mat];
mat = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, -2, 2}, {-3, 3, 3}}

r = MapIndexed[Function[{x, n},
    Which[x < 0,
     p = Position[mat[[All, First@n]], x_ /; x > 0]; p = DeleteCases[p, n]; 
      (Append[#, First@n] & /@ p),

     x > 0, p = Position[mat[[All, First@n]], x_ /; x < 0]; p = DeleteCases[p, n]; 
      (Append[#, First@n] & /@ p)]]
   , Diagonal[mat]];

Flatten[r, 1]

(* {{3, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 2}} *)
```

for

```
mat = {{-1, -1, 1}, {2, -2, 2}, {-3, 3, 3}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*{{2, 1}, {3, 2}}*)
```

for

```
 mat = {{-1, -1, 1, 0}, {2, -2, 2, 5}, {-3, 3, 3, 4}, {2, 2, 2, 2}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 {{2, 1}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}}
```